# How do the 35mm Zeiss Loxia vs Sony Zeiss Sonnar compare for IQ for landscapes?

Tags: lens, landscape, zeiss, comparison, sony-alpha

How do the Sony Zeiss Sonnar 35mm f/2.8 and Zeiss Loxia 35mm f/2 lenses compare  on the Sony a7? (I am interested more with image quality than ergonomics, build quality, price, etc.)

I am particularly curious about sharpness and detail preservation for large landscape prints. Also, good corners in the f/5.6 to f/14 range. Lastly, chromatic aberration around high contrast areas (like purple fringing around leaves in front of a bright sky).

Comment: I don't have the loxia yet, but it doesn't seem like it is a line centered on resolution and correction. It seems to be a line that revives the classics. I have the sony and it is excellent within the range you are mentioning. I haven't used it on a7r yet. Maybe there it reaches its limits.

Comment: Huh. That would be disappointing. For the extra money, I was hoping for better glass.

Comment: The extra money is justified by extra aperture opening! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the Sony Zeiss 35mm f/2.8 on the A7ʀ at f/5.6:

[image]

And here's a crop of the extreme bottom left corner (right click -> "view image to see it at 100%"):

[image]

Sharpness in the corners is very impressive for a 36 megapixel sensor. Chromatic aberration is well handled by lightroom, I've not had any problems with it

I don't have the Loxia to compare it to but that's a lens geared towards a classic rendering and bokeh, I wouldn't expect it to match the Sony lens for landscape use, if you're after image quality stopped down then I would definitely go for the Sony Zeiss f/2.8 lens.

Comment: As it turns out, people are tending to agree with you: https://fstoppers.com/originals/fstoppers-reviews-beautifully-crafted-zeiss-loxia-35mm-f2-lens-67394 The Loxia still seems like a solid lens, but the design is more about classic feel and luxury than performance.